# how can I delete entities in core data with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to have the delete button delete some elements from my core data stack. I am not sure where I am going wrong, the function is supposed to delete the terms and definitions but deletes neither.

```
@IBAction func deletePressed(_ sender: Any) {
  do {
    fetched = try context.fetch(Card.fetchRequest())
    for object in fetched {
      context.delete(object)
    }
  } catch {
    print("Error")
  }
  ad.saveContext()
  fetchData()
}
func fetchData() {
  do {
    fetched = try context.fetch(Card.fetchRequest())
    for each in fetched {
      termLabel.text = each.term!
      definitionLabel.text = each.definition!
      fetchedTerm.append(each.term!)
      fetchedDefinition.append(each.definition!)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try `fetchedTerm.removeAll()` and `fetchedDefinition.removeAll()` at the start of your `fetchData` function - Really though you shouldn't copy the data into different arrays. Just keep an array of `Card`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast `(object as NSManagedObject)` in the `context.delete()` function.